# How to put multiple selectedRow inside an SQL join Query

Tags: javascript, mysql

Hello I tried to search from here but found no luck. I'd like to ask if would it be possible to have a multiple selected row be a condition inside a query?

I have table employeesT which has id, email, company_name and etc

So when selecting rows from this table from my page, there is another table down below which should show a joined table of employeesT and designationsT which should show id, email, designations etc.

Here is my query (email is used for the join)

```
SELECT et.id, 
et.email,
dt.month,
dt.designation_status,
dt.team_size
FROM employeesT AS et
JOIN designationsT AS dt
ON dt.email = dt.email;
WHERE sa.email IS ({{{ employeesT.selectedRow.data }}})
```

I am not sure on what to put additionally on my SQL Query for a condition to only show those from my multiple selected rows. Please help.

EDIT - I was trying for my query like

```
SELECT et.id, 
et.email,
dt.month,
dt.designation_status,
dt.team_size
FROM employeesT AS et
JOIN designationsT AS dt
ON dt.email = dt.email;
WHERE et.email IS ({{{ employeesT.selectedRow.data }}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean?
Do you only want to select rows from employees if a record in the table designations exits?

```
SELECT et.id, 
       et.email,
       dt.month,
       dt.designation_status,
      dt.team_size
FROM employeesT AS et
INNER JOIN designationsT AS dt
ON et.email = dt.email
WHERE et.id IN(1, 3, 4, 20)
```

or

```
SELECT et.id, 
       et.email,
       dt.month,
       dt.designation_status,
      dt.team_size
FROM employeesT AS et
INNER JOIN designationsT AS dt
ON et.email = dt.email
WHERE et.email IN('email1@test.nl', 'email2@test.nl', 'email3@test.nl')
```

updated the query.

Comment: Sorry to confuse but from my page, I have a table showing all of the employee lists. I can select 1 to multiple employees from there. My goal is when I select those employees, it should show those selected from the below table of my page with join for employeesT and designationsT and only for my selected rows (i used a checkbox to select)

Comment: kindly see my updated question

Comment: You can add a where clause. I have updated the query.

Comment: yes from my edit. but im not particularly sure on what to add on my where clause perhaps.

Comment: You are close - see my query.

Comment: Hmmm still not going through with my WHERE et.email IN({{ employeesTable.selectedRow.data }})

Comment: Added another query. What is "{{ employeesTable.selectedRow.data }}" ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248406/discussion-between-tom-and-macy-creed).

Comment: on the chat page now Tom, thank you!